# vtd-xml: Autopilot: declareVariableExpr

Tags: vtd-xml

Java VTD-XML has the following API

```
class AutoPilot{
    declareVariableExpr(java.lang.String varName, java.lang.String varExpr);
}
Register the binding between a variableExpr name and variableExpr expression
```

I have successfully used it for simple variable bindings like:

```
abc => "some value"
```

and Autopilot can run expressions like

```
ap.selectXpath("concat(/a/b/text(),  $abc)");
ap.evalXPathToString()
```

My question is:

The API says it binds a variable to a variable expression.
**how to bind to a variable expression? and what is the usage of binding to an 'expression'?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
ap.declareVariableExpr("my_expr","/a/b/c");

Comment: thanks. but what is the use of binding the variable to an expression. that is my real question. variable can be bound to a value. you mean "/a/b/c" is a value?

Comment: Yep, it will be evaluated to a value,  eg. String boolean or a double depending on  the context